# How to use the emoji module on python IDLE?

Tags: python, emoji

The emoji module is not working in the IDLE. It was a few hours ago but all of a sudden it has stopped. How can I print emojis in the Python IDLE? It works in the Jupyter Notebook but not anymore on the IDLE.

```
import emoji 

print(emoji.emojize('Python is :thumbsup:',
use_aliases=True))
```

Instead of printing: 
    Python is

It prints:

```
print(emoji.emojize('Python is :thumbsup:',       use_aliases=True))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters position 10-10: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk
```

Comment: As it indicates the error message IDLE is done with Tk, and this library does not support those characters so there is no solution.

Comment: I am not too sure about that because it was working before. Now that I uninstalled and reinstalled the emoji module it is displaying: module emoji has no attribute emojize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this unicode issue has been seen in python 3.6 and older versions, to resolve it you can do 2 things as below.

1) Upgrade python as python 3.8 and use direct unicode or emoji module to get the result of emoji symbol. Note that you can get the result for some face emojies by using python IDLE 3.8 but for other emojies use conda.

See my code to understand more:

```
**#use direct unicode to get the result**
>>> print('\U00002668')
♨
>>> print('\U000026D1')
⛑
>>> print('\U0001F600')

>>> print('\U0001F606')

>>> print("\N{winking face}")


**#Use emoji module by install it as pip install emoji**
>>> import emoji
>>> print(emoji.emojize(":winking_face_with_tongue:"))

>>> print(emoji.emojize(":thumbs_up:"))

>>> print(emoji.emojize(":man:"))

>>> print(emoji.emojize(":woman:"))

>>> print(emoji.emojize(":baby:"))

>>> print(emoji.emojize(":girl:"))
```

For unicode of emoji module, check link as [This link gives a unicode name or code to use in our program.](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f469)

2) Install conda and then write your code in jupyter notebook and get the result.

Answer (score 0):

We can resolve this error in older versions(before 3.7) of python by using unicode as "\uxxxx" (which use in unicode for C/C++/java).

```
#code to create a emoji of eye in python 3.6 and older versions
>>> print("\uD83D\uDC40")
```